# How can we check for uniqueness of solution in this example?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, lipschitz-functions

Consider this first-order ODE
$$
\dot{y}=f(x,y)=-y^{3}e^{2x}+4
$$

with $y(0)=y_{0}$.

I was able to verify existence of a solution. How can we prove uniqueness of solution for $x\geq0$? we know that $f$ is continuous in $x$, but I don't think that $f$ is global or local Lipschitz as I am unable to bound the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. Any suggestions?

Comment: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is *locally* bounded.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant I am unable to bound $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, it was a typo @AnneBauval

Comment: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is *locally* bounded.